# How to get the global time (not system specific time) in android

Tags: android

I would like to get the current global time in android, meaning, even if the user changed the system's time, I would like to get the correct time.

How can I do that?

Comment: Contact an SNTP server.

Comment: @CommonsWare How do you do that?

Comment: Try [this library](https://github.com/AllanHasegawa/Tempo) or [this library](https://github.com/instacart/truetime-android). Or, see if there are other libraries for SNTP time access.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To do that you must first have access to the location of the device.
You can connect through a web service such as:

https://timezonedb.com/

https://www.worldtimeserver.com/

Through its APIs you can know the date and time of the zone in which the device is located. If you need more information on how to read restful or xml file of the web service answer, tell me.

The best solution is:

If you have a server. Make your own web service that verifies that the date and time of the Android device on which your App is running matches that of your server.

Comment: What if the timezone isn't important to me. Is it possible to do it easier without the need of a time zone?

Comment: The time zone is the one that will tell you if there are changes, in the winter and summer times in that area. The easiest solution is to use the time from one of your servers. If your app only runs in one country you can use the time of one yours servers.  But if your app is going to be in several countries you will also need the location of the device

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out